# Python: Append a list to the same list

Tags: python-2.7

I am having a very basic doubt. 
Consider the following example:

**Case 1:**

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
a.append(b) #print a will give [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

**Case 2:**

```
a=[1,2,3]
a.append(a) # print a gives [1,2,3,...]
```

I understand the ***.append*** in python appends the values of the variable to the end of the variable it's appended to. However, i don't understand the behavior of the '**...'** in the Case 2.

Comment: Look at `a[3]`, or `a[2:4]` to explore.

Comment: a[3] gives me the same value as  list a. Am i looking at a recursion?

Comment: Yes, @SeasonalShot :) Also try `a[0] = 9` then `print a` and `print a[3]`.

Comment: @askewchan Yes, i got it!. It is a recursion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dots indicate that a list contains a reference to itself. It just avoids an infinite recursion during the print.